# how to caculate the ip address life time?

Tags: influxdb

Now I mod the crontab's shell,it run every 10minutes, only ip changed,it write into influxdb,database looks like:

Can I caculate the none NULL data's ELAPSED time ?

```
> select * from "exec_wanip"
name: exec_wanip
time                host    value
----                ----    -----
1542951090000000000 monitor
1542951140000000000 monitor
1542951150000000000 monitor 118.114.187.199
1542951160000000000 monitor
1542951170000000000 monitor
1542951180000000000 monitor
1542951190000000000 monitor
1542951200000000000 monitor
1542951210000000000 monitor
1542951810000000000 monitor
1542952410000000000 monitor
1542953010000000000 monitor
```

---

I record WAN ip via crontab,here is the data in influxdb,and ip address is variable.

how could I caculate the life time of each ip address ?

```
> select * from exec_wanip
name: exec_wanip
time                host    value
----                ----    -----
1542856250000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542856850000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542857450000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542858050000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542858650000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542859250000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542859850000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542860450000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542861050000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542861650000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542862250000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542862850000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542863450000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542864050000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542864650000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
1542865250000000000 monitor 118.114.187.208
```

Comment: That's hardly possible with your current schema. If you use 'ip' as tag and cronjob is periodic than query like this `select count(value) from exec_wanip group by ip` should give you number of occurrences per ip. Multiply by cron period to get life time.

Comment: Hi,I mod my shell script,could you please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Your modified script is still not setting ip as tag.
And my guess is that you actually store empty strings as value - not NULLs.
The query for this data:

> SELECT 600*count(value) AS Lifetime_seconds FROM exec_wanip WHERE value<>''

Using filtering on values in WHERE clause is not good for InfluxDB performance in general. I would recommend to change the cron script to put data with line protocol lines like these into your db:

> exec_wanip,host=monitor,ip=118.114.187.208 value=118.114.187.208
>   exec_wanip,host=monitor,ip=118.114.187.199 value=118.114.187.199
>   ...

using curl POST or cli INSERT equivalent.

> curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb" --data-binary 'exec_wanip,host=monitor,ip=118.114.187.208 value=118.114.187.208'
>
> curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb" --data-binary 'exec_wanip,host=monitor,ip=118.114.187.199 value=118.114.187.199'

After this is done you'll be able to calculate ip life time with query like this:

> SELECT 600*count(value) AS Lifetime_seconds FROM exec_wanip GROUP BY ip

Add WHERE clause to query with time range selection as needed.
Note: anything can be used as value here, not necessarily ip address, for example 'up'/'down', etc.